# Find strings that start with [[ and specific string

Tags: python, regex

I have these strings:

```
[[:File:Example.jpg]]
[[:File:Example.jpg|this example]]
[[Media:Example.jpg]]
[[Georgia (U.S. state)|Georgia]]
[[Arkansas]]
[[Canada]]
[[Virginia]]
[[Image:Houstonia longifolia - Long Leaf Bluet 2.jpg|thumb|left]]
```

I want to extract with `re` the strings that start with `[[Image` or `[[Media:` or `[[:file:`

Comment: And what is the problem? This regex is awfully trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex

Outputs only if there is `[[Image`, `[[Media:` or `[[:File:` at the beginning of the string (also added `re.IGNORECASE` flag to give the match at any case)

`\[\[(?:Image|Media|:File):.+]]`

Code:

```py
import re

a = '''[[:File:Example.jpg]]
[[:File:Example.jpg|this example]]
[[Media:Example.jpg]]
[[Georgia (U.S. state)|Georgia]]
[[Arkansas]]
[[Canada]]
[[Virginia]]
[[Image:Houstonia longifolia - Long Leaf Bluet 2.jpg|thumb|left]]'''

print(re.findall(r'\[\[(?:Image|Media|:File):.+]]', a, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

Outputs:

```
[
 '[[:File:Example.jpg]]',
 '[[:File:Example.jpg|this example]]',
 '[[Media:Example.jpg]]',
 '[[Image:Houstonia longifolia - Long Leaf Bluet 2.jpg|thumb|left]]'
]
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL0apa/2)**

Tell me if its not working...

Answer (score 1):

To find the strings beginning with `[[:File:`, you can use:

```
  re.search(r"\[\[:File.*?]]", your_strings)
```

Same with `[[Media:` and `[[Image`:

```
  re.search(r"\[\[Media:.*?]]", your_strings)

  re.search(r"\[\[Image.*?]]", your_strings)
```

See this [example](https://regex101.com/r/H62bHK/1).